# why is the following code wrong?

Tags: c, algorithm, output

I recently faced an interview question on what's the hidden problem with the following code. I was unable to detect it .Can anyone help?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[10];
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));

    gets(buff);

    printf("\n The buffer entered is [%s]\n",buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset` needs `string.h`

Comment: "Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead." - `gets` man page

Comment: Your code works....add `fflush(stdin)` and `string.h` http://ideone.com/SDxb3f

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: No, `sizeof` on an array will return the size of the array.

Comment: when string entered beyond 10. output get crash

Comment: @Fred Ah, yes that's true for stack memory.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: It's true for any array, as long as it's still an array. Trouble is, if you pass it to a function it'll decay to a pointer.

Comment: @Fred I'm not sure what you mean whereas when you declare an array on the heap, all you have is a pointer. E.g. `char *buff = malloc(100*sizeof(char)); printf("%u\n", sizeof(buff));` will only ever give `8` on a 64-bit system. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: You could declare a static array. That is neither stack nor heap.

Comment: @Bill `fflush()` is not defined for input streams. Never use `fflush(stdin)`, it's a bug, and Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple You don't really declare arrays on the heap. You allocate some quantity of memory and `malloc` returns a `void *` which is automatically converted to the correct pointer type. You can't even cast to array types as far as I know--you can only declare an array.

Comment: The `buff` in your example is a mere pointer, not an array, even though it points to the beginning of an array. `typedef char C[100]; C* c = malloc(sizeof *c);` will give you a pointer to a dynamically allocated array. Note that there are no brackets necessary for `sizeof` here, unlike when using it with a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function *gets* accepts a string from stdin and does not check the capacity of the buffer.This may result in buffer overflow. The standard function [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) can be used here.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` could return much more than 10 characters.

gets is really problematic because you can't tell it to only fill 'buff' up to a length of 10.

Answer (score 1):

check the  [Bugs Section of this manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) which says

```
   Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing
   the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because
   gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer,
   it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer
   security.  Use fgets() instead.

   It is not advisable to mix calls to input functions from the stdio
   library with low-level calls to read(2) for the file descriptor
   associated with the input stream; the results will be undefined and
   very probably not what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use fgets()/ scanf() over gets().

Answer (score 0):

by using the function gets() you don't have the option to limit the user to a certian text length, which may cause a buffer overflow exception. That is why you should not use it.

Try to use fgets() instead:
fgets(buff, MAX_LENGTH_ stdin);

Good luck!